# Map list of boolean observables into output that emits true whenever all inputs are true

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Say I have *n* `Boolean` `Observables` (`O1`, `O2`,...,`On`) that emit flags indicating, let's say, checkbox selection states.

For example, for *n* = 3, we would have something like this (`T` =`true` and `F` = `false`):

```
O1    - T ------------------- F ----------------------- T ------

O2    - F ------------ T ---------------------------------------

O3    - T -------------------------- F -------- T --------------
```

I want to get an output `Boolean` `Observable` (`Oout`) that emits `true` when all the latest emissions are `true` or `false` otherwise. Something like this:

```
O1    - T ------------------- F ----------------------- T ------

O2    - F ------------ T ---------------------------------------

O3    - T -------------------------- F -------- T --------------

================================================================

Oout  - F ------------ T ---- F ----------------------- T ------
```

Is there a fancy way to do this in **RxJava** (that is, without the need to create a custom observable and monitoring the state myself. I feel like a couple of operators can do the job)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static method `Observable.combineLatest(List<Observable<T>> observables, FuncN<?> combineFunction)` is the thing you are looking for.

You pass in a list of observables and a combine function, which determines the output, in your case just a for cycle will be sufficient to check if all of them are true.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about this one. By using this with `distinctUntilChanged()` I can achieve what I want. Thanks!